# _countof in stdlib broken: why?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I have a weird problem. In a very simple example (**it's c, not c++**):

```
int test[3];
auto n = _countof(test);
```

I have error E0304:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error
>   (active)  E0304   no instance of function template "__countof_helper"
>   matches the argument
>   list

I was not having this with visual studio 15.6.7, it appeared with 15.7 update. Toolset was not explicitely changed, it's still:

> platform toolset: Visual Studio 2017 (v141)

What is happening ? How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is reported from the IntelliSense engine and would not affect a build of a project. To avoid annoyance in the IntelliSense, the following workaround may be applied:

In `vcruntime.h` included by your project (you should be able to get to the right one by performing *Go To Definition* on `_countof` usage, followed by *Go To Definition* on `_crt_countof` in the definition of `_countof`), replace:

```
#if defined _M_X64 || defined _M_ARM || defined _M_ARM64
```

with:

```
#if (defined _M_X64 || defined _M_ARM || defined _M_ARM64) && !__INTELLISENSE__
```

Microsot will be working on a proper fix so the workaround will not be needed in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`std::size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) instead:

```
#include <iterator>
int main()
{
    int x[3];
    auto const xs{::std::size(x)};
}
```

No changes are required after switching to `std::array`, `std::vector` or compatible wrapper:

```
::std::array<int, 3> ax{};
auto const axs{::std::size(ax)};
::std::vector<int> vx{0, 0, 0};
auto const vxs{::std::size(vx)};
```

Comment: @Soleil I've just got 15.7 update notification. Going to check it in a minute. But those macros tend to be suspicious. They've broke `offsetof` just recently after switching to some new intrinsic...

Comment: So, in a nutshell, instead of writing c, I go c++ ? (I had this macro in DX12 samples from MS).

Comment: Try avoiding the use of functions starting with underscore. These are reserved for internal use. If you have C++17 this is definitely the right solution; If not you may use the template in my answer. _countof is most likely not portable to other compilers/std-libs.

Comment: @Soleil Developing DirectX (and COM-based) applications in C is pretty hardcore.

Comment: @kiloalphaindia Actually only symbols starting with two underscores or an underscore followed by Uppercase character are reserved for internal use.

Comment: @VTT totally right, but would you trust Microsoft (or anybody else) to care?! OK, ommiting sarcasm: even in a single undescore case I would be careful. (btw. there are double undersores in the question, I didn't check which is correct, because most likely either is not supposed to be used by a (non-std-library) programmer)

Comment: Actually `_countof` leads ot a double underscore: `#define _countof __crt_countof`, then `#define __crt_countof(_Array) (sizeof(*__countof_helper(_Array)) + 0)` and `template <typename _CountofType, size_t _SizeOfArray>
        char (*__countof_helper(_UNALIGNED _CountofType (&_Array)[_SizeOfArray]))[_SizeOfArray];`

Comment: @Soleil I'm not able to confirm this issue, for me `_countof` still works fine after upgrading to 15.7. But it is still worth switching to `std::size`.

Comment: @VTT Is it ethical to solve a c problem by swithing locally to c++17 ? I switched to Intel icc 2018, keeping `_countof`, no problem. Actually I got the error only in the editor, the build succeeds with MSVC. I desactivated R#, which uses LLVM, the "error" persisted.

Comment: Unless you have a good reason to stick to C, it is always a good idea to switch to C++ as programming in C++ is a lot more efficient, structured and typesafe.

Comment: Double underscore anywhere in a name is reserved in C++, but only leading double underscore is reserved in C.

Answer (score 1):

For people not having a C++17 compiler this will do the trick:

```
template <class T, std::size_t N>
size_t countof(const T (&array)[N])
{
    return N;
}
```

Comment: What's happening with c++17 ?

Comment: C++17 defines std::size(...) therfore you should use that as in the answer by VTT